# Is there a specific order to write loaders in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I was following a Webpack tutorial on Udemy and got pretty excited and typed the 'use' array ahead of the tutor. This is the way I typed... and didn't get the output.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "style-loader" },
        ],
      },
      
    ],
  },
```

I couldn't find where did I go wrong but later when typed the way the tutor did the build ran without breaking. This is the correct code..

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
        ],
    ],
  },
```

So is it wrong to enter the sass-loader first and style-loader later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loaders are evaluated bottom to top. In your case, you want to make sure the sass code is converted to standard css, and `url()` and `import()` rules are resolved properly, before your styles are added to the DOM. So yes in this case, the order matters.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated